# Migrate Eclipse 3.3 features/plugins to Eclipse Juno 4.2

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm using an old version of Eclipse (Eclipse Platform 3.3) which uses a product comprising a large number of features and plugins. The product vendor is no longer in business so I'm looking at the viability of migrating the features/plugins to run on Eclipse Juno 4.2. The JAR files in the plugins were compiled on Java 5 and will be running in a Java 7 environment (no source code). Has anyone had any experience of doing such a thing, is it possible and is there any reference material? I really can't think of any more detail to add to this question, so I'm going to go with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an update site for the features? If so, did you tried to install the feature/plugins on a fresh eclipse 4.2?

If you can identify the files in plugins and features folder of the product you try to use with 4.2, did you tried to copy them on the plugins/features folder of a clean 4.2?

Eclipse 4 application platform provides a compatibility layer for 3.x plugins, so it may just work.

http://xseignard.github.com/demoCamp2012/prez/#22

You can also find some literature about migrating 3.x plugins to 4.X there : http://www.vogella.com/blog/2012/11/13/getting-your-eclipse-plug-ins-ready-for-eclipse-4/

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yes, I copied into the features & plugins folder of a cleanly installed 4.2 Juno. There are a lot of exceptions being thrown when I start eclipse with -debug, however the useful info is outside the scroll buffer. I'm sure I can resolve this pretty easily. I'll have a read through the information in the links you've posted.